# Panel toggleDown only the checkbox checked. Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, slidetoggle

I want to create the slideToggle panel only able to slide down and back after the checkbox checked. If the checkbox not checked the slideToggle does not have to work and give me an alert

> The panel can not be opened!

But I can not concatenate that.

```js
$("#header").click(function(){
  $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
$("chckbox").click(function(){
  alert("The panel can not be opened!")
});
```

```css
#header, #panel{
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
#panel{
  height: 80px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<caption for="chckbox">(On/Off)</caption>
<input type="checkbox" id="chckbox">
<div id="header">Panel</div>
<div id="panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check status of checkbox using [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked) property on click on `#header`

```
$("#header").click(function(){
  if ($("#chckbox")[0].checked)
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  else
    alert("The panel can not be opened!")
});
```

```js
$("#header").click(function(){
  if ($("#chckbox")[0].checked)
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  else
    console.log("The panel can not be opened!")
});
```

```css
#header, #panel{
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
#panel{
  height: 80px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<caption for="chckbox">(On/Off)</caption>
<input type="checkbox" id="chckbox">
<div id="header">Panel</div>
<div id="panel"></div>
```

Comment: No. If the checkbox check I able to toggleDown the panel. 
Not the checkbox is checked to toggleDown the panel.

Comment: @rzdavid Updated

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need.